# Node are going out of canvas and container

Tags: vis.js

I am using Vis for creating network. How i can stop node going out of canvas when any one drag the nodes. Here is screen shot of my problem.

[image]

Here you can see that i have drag out one node of of view. How i can stop user from dragging node out of container or canvas size. User can move nodes within the view port.  Any method or any workaround would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.